# Can't turn off iRST

Tags: system-installation

I just bought Acer laptop and I can't install ubuntu 20.04, it asks me to turn off RST before installing.  But there is no option to turn off RST or change hard disk controller to AHCI. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Many vendors removed the option to disable RST in BIOS probably because people disable it and then can't boot Windows.

If you don't need Windows, RST doesn't create any problems. But dual boot is tricky.

I see the easiest way to create new partition table, reinstall Windows without using any RAID and then install Ubuntu.

Another way is to use the RAID, but that needs some difficult manual tuning of boot loader for Ubuntu, because it doesn't support these RAIDs very well yet.

It also depends on hardware and how it is configured for Windows.